# How to avoid that the first value of an input being a white space?

Tags: html

I want to validate that the first character not being a white space.
The client can put numbers, letters or characters and also white spaces between words but the first character doesn't might being a white space.

```
<input class="form-control"
name="description" 
placeholder="Add your description" 
ng-model="$ctrl.description" 
pattern="^[\\S]([\\wéáíóúñÑ,.:-¿?!() ])+$"
required>
```

What can I put in the pattern to validate that in html code?.